# How to sum properties of objects in array using array methods

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need some help, I am trying to merge this objects by name property but I am stuck, I am trying to resolve this by array methods and not with for loops.

```
var arr = [
  {name: 'lucas', number: 20}, 
  {name: 'lucas', number: 22},
  {name: 'luna', number: 10}, 
  {name: 'luna', number: 23},
  {name: 'diego', number: 15}
];
          

var expectedOutput = [
  {name: 'lucas', number: 42},
  {name: 'luna', number: 33},
  {name: 'diego', number: 15}
];
```

Comment: `reduce` is everything what you need

Comment: i know, but im trying to understand how to apply reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{name:'lucas',number:20},{name:'lucas',number:22},{name:'luna',number:10},{name:'luna',number:23},{name:'diego',number:15}];

let finalResult = arr.reduce((result, obj) => {
  if (result[obj.name]) {
    result[obj.name].number += obj.number || 0
  } else {
    result[obj.name] = { ...obj};
  }
  return result
}, {})

finalResult = Object.values(finalResult)

console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `reduce` and take `Object.values` in order to get the expected output. Here is the working example:

```js
var arr = [{name: 'lucas', number: 20},  {name: 'lucas', number: 22}, {name: 'luna', number: 10} , {name: 'luna', number: 23}, {name: 'diego', number: 15}];

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {name, number})=>{
   acc[name] = acc[name] || {name, number:0};
   acc[name].number+=number;
   return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```